# How to register click events from things under?

Tags: javascript, html, events, click

On my page, I have a two tables side by side. Both tables have stuff that you can click on. However using `marigin` and `position relative`, I moved the second table to be right under the first table. The problem is that I can click things in the first table and it will work, but when I click things in the second table, it does not register....

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of things, links?

Comment: show us some html/css/javascript

Comment: Their like nested tables with onclick events on their td cells.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is in the shop today, you'll need to post some code.

Comment: Right under as in below like you did a <br /> or right under like one's floated over the other with different z-index

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers support `pointer-events: none;` property so the object would be transparent for mouse events, but it is not cross-browser solution. IE does not support it at all. Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera do.

Comment: I would need support for IE8 actually.

Comment: I fixed th problem by using divs and float css.

Comment: if you fixed your problem with float then you didn't describe problem properly

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're running into is that you have an html element on top of another html element. Click events will be fired on whichever of them is the top-most element. You can adjust this with the [z-index css property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) of the elements. The higher the value, the higher the layer on the stack.

However, if you really need that table on top of the other table, you can use pointer-events: none; in most browsers, as Flash Thunder mentioned.

If you need this to work in ie8 or older, there are some complicated solutions out there:
http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

The real question here is, why are you doing this? It sounds like you have a shaky solution to an unknown problem. Could you explain why you need a table on top of another table?